# Shortcut for the create property function in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Could anybody please tell me shortcut for the Create - Property function of Visual Studio's context menu. I know that Create - Method's shortcut is CTRL + K + M, but I can't find similar shortcut to create property.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some exploration, I've discovered that there is no default shortcut set for this command. It could be set in visual studio options dialog (Tools -> Options -> Environment\Keyboard) Command is called "Edit.GenerateProperty".

Answer (score 0):

Please check following link

http://www.itscodingtime.com/post/Visual-Studio-2010-Keyboard-Mouse-Shortcuts.aspx

Hope, it might help you.

**Edit:**
This topic is already discussed here 
[Shortcut to create properties in Visual Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3871270/short-cut-to-create-properties-in-visual-studio)

Comment: It was similar question but not the same. Snippet is useful, but its a little bit different. Please, look at my comment to the LolCoder's answer. I've already checked that article, but didn't find answer.

Answer (score 0):

Type the `prop` and you can see `prop` in your intellisence and enter `prop` one....Then, you can change name of property with its type according to you choice(Default type is `Type` and default property naem is `type`) like in following way:

```
public TYPE Type { get; set; }
```

Another way of adding property is by pressing `Ctrl + R, Ctrl+E` when your cursor is around the field....

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but that is not what I'm looking for. Snippets allow me to generate property when I'm editing class itself, but then I write something like myObject.Property = "123"; and property is not defined in that object I may call context menu on "Property" and select Create -> Property, it will generate property string Property {get; set;} in myObject's class. I can do it using context menu, but it would be more comfortable for me to use shortcut to call this function.