# Visual Studio 2010 autocomplete - how does the presenter do this?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I'm watching the video in *[Entity Framework Code First to a New Database](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj193542)*. Notice how the presenter writes the class Blog and everything is automatically written. How can I do that?

Answer (score 3):

This is using the IntelliSense features of the IDE. If you watch, the presenter types 'prop' and then tabs to get code completion. Try it.

Here's a question that is relevant: *[Shortcut to create properties in Visual Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3871270/short-cut-to-create-properties-in-visual-studio)*

For further information (and further code snippets), check out [the MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z41h7fat%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and if you want to create your own see *[Creating Code Snippets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165393(v=vs.80).aspx)*.

Answer (score 1):

These are called *code snippets*. Visual Studio contains many predefined ones, but you can also create **[your own](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165394.aspx)**. They are part of the IDE's IntelliSense code-completion tool.

Answer (score 0):

Try <kbd>p</kbd><kbd>tab</kbd><kbd>tab</kbd>; this is shorthand for using the snippet named `prop` - you can then change the type and name, using <kbd>←</kbd> and <kbd>→</kbd> to move between tokens.

Answer (score 0):

That feature is called code snippets.

To automatically enter a template for an auto property as shown at the start of the video, simply type the shortcut code `prop` and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd> to invoke [IntelliSense](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intelli-sense). This will create the empty auto property boilerplate code, and you just need to type the important parts, for example, type and name.

See the MSDN article *[How to: Insert IntelliSense Code Snippets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165399(v=vs.100).aspx)* for more information.