# How getter should look in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, getter-setter

I have seen this kind of code in C#:

```
  private int id {get;set;}
```

but I would only create getter for the field, because if there is get and set for it is the same as public field **is the only way is**:

```
public int getId(){return id;}
```

How to automatically generate only getters in VS2010?

Comment: This is very Similar:

[How to create Autoporpertys](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3871270/short-cut-to-create-properties-in-visual-studio)

Comment: That is *not* the same as a public field. For at least two reasons.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you have implemented is known as an `Automatic Property` they look like this:

```
private string Name { get; set; }
```

Automatic properties  merely *syntactical sugar* and in reality, provide a succinct, quick way to implement this code:

```
private string _name;
public string Name 
{ 
    get { return _name; } 
    set { _name = value; } 
}
```

You could disregard automatic properties, using manual proeprties and simply remove the `get`. Or use automatic properties and make the property's value read only to external members by marking the `get` with the private access modifier:

```
public string Name { get; private set; }
```

The code you say you would usually use, is never really needed in C# because properties, in reality are just methods in disguise and should be used as a better convention:

```
public int getId(){return id;} //bad
```

Comment: @RobertKilar Mostly a convention but if you want to understand the benefits 'under the hood' read: http://csharpindepth.com/articles/chapter8/propertiesmatter.aspx

Comment: "properties are methods in disguise" is a rather unfortunate statement. C# properties are implemented using CLR methods, but it's not a good idea to conflate these two abstraction levels. For instance, from C#, you're not allowed to call the emitted methods directly; they are treated specially when using reflection; and who knows what else. So it's obvious they're not *just* methods.

Answer (score 7):

Do you mean how do you implement a readonly property? If so try:

```
public int Id { get; private set;}
```

Comment: But what if I don't want any setter, any.

Comment: If you are writing a base `class`, you can use the `protected` keyword instead of `private` so that derived classes can also set this property. `internal` can also be used, though the cases are pretty rare. `set` is required for auto-generated properties because you would have no other way to set the value of this property (there's no backing storage as if there was a member field defined).

Answer (score 1):

right click on the field, refactor, encapsulated field

Comment: that generates getter and setter? he wants to generate only getters.

Answer (score 1):

No they are not the same. A property compiles to one or two methods bound to a property. E.g.:

```
public int Foo { get; private set; }
```

compiles to the IL code that works like this:

```
private int _foo;
public int Foo { get_Foo = get, set_Foo = set }

public int get_Foo() { return _foo; }
private void set_Foo(int value) { _foo = value; }
```

In other words: properties are methods, while fields are not. That's why you can do things like:

```
public int Foo { get { return 0; } }
```

which compiles to:

```
public int Foo { get_Foo = get }

public int get_Foo() { return 0;}
```

**update**

Okay now I understand your question... the answer is the last part that shows how a getter-only works as well as what it does :-)

Answer (score 1):

This is very similar:

[How to create Autoproperties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3871270/short-cut-to-create-properties-in-visual-studio)

Just type `prop` and than write your Type and press Tab to write your name.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want a property that is publicly available, but can only be set by the class.  Is it something like this:

```
 public class Entity
 {
     public void Entity()
     {
         ID = ...;  // Some unique id
     }

     public int ID { get; private set; }
 }
```

This allows the class Entity to read and write the ID, but other classes can only read the ID.