# How to set property for fields declared in one row

Tags: c#, properties

As int the subject

```
public String imie, nazwisko{get; private set;}
```

I would apply get/set rule for both of them `imie` and `nazwisko` in the same row

Comment: Are you trying to define 2 properties in 1 line? If so you can't.

Comment: You can't do that. Each property has to have its own declaration.

Comment: if I can declare many fields of the same type in one row I would like to do it here to.

Comment: Why? What does having these in one "row" give you?

Comment: And those are **not** fields. They are **properties**.

Comment: I just explained the difference between **properties** and **fields** on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14418612/how-getter-should-look/14418649#14418649

Comment: @Oded just java manner if I have ten ints in the class definition I don't want write int val; int val2; int...... ; int val10

Comment: Well, to be fair, you _can_ declare them in one row by skipping the line break: `public string imie {get; private set; } public string nazwisko {get; private set; }` but of course, this isn't actually what Robert is going for. :)

Comment: @RobertKilar - You can declare fields that way. The `{get; set;}` syntax is not for fields - it is for properties.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to declare multiple *fields* in one statement, you can:

```
public string imie, nazwisko, whatever;
```

What you have posted is an attempt to do the same with *properties*, which is not possible (not with shared getter/setter declaration).

Though, of course these *can* be on one line:

```
public string imie{get; private set;} public string nazwisko{get; private set;}
```

I suggest reading about [fields](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173118.aspx) and [properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9fsa0sw.aspx) on MSDN.