# ASP.NET Core tutorial error 'The value 'http://msdn.com' is not valid for Url

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core

I'm running the app in this [Microsoft Tutorial](https://docs.efproject.net/en/latest/platforms/aspnetcore/new-db.html#run-the-application) and when I try to enter a url in the input box of the app (for instance, `http://msdn.com` or `http://blogs.msdn.com/adonet` as shown in the tutorial) and click submit I get the following validation error:

```
The value 'http://msdn.com' is not valid for Url.
```

When I debug the application I notice that in the following code of the tutorial the ModelState.IsValid value is showing as 'false'. What is missing here and how can it be fixed?

```
public IActionResult Create(Blog blog)
        {
            if(ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                _context.Blogs.Add(blog);
                _context.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            return View(blog);
        }
```

**Points to note**:

1. I'm using latest ASP.NET Core 1.0 and VS2015-Update 3 [released on June 27, 2016] on windows 8.1
2. In the Creat.chtml view of the tutorial, `<input asp-for="Url" class="form-control" />` was initially showing as readonly so I added type="text" attribute there and it became read/write
3. My app is an exact copy of the tutorial (I did copy/past) except that instead of choosing 'No Authentication' I chose 'Individual User Accounts' option when creating the poroject. But that, I think, should not make any difference.

**UPDATE**

I added `var errors = ModelState.Values.SelectMany(v => v.Errors);` just above `if(ModelState.IsValid)` statement and I see the following in the debug window showing the values of `error collection` but can't figure out the cause of error. Maybe. someone can help:

**UPDATE 2**:

I **found my mistake**. I was using int datatype in `public int Url { get; set; }` property of the Blog class instead of using string. Changed it to string and it's working now. Someone may help what the error in image is saying.

[image]

Comment: What does the error in the `ModelState` say?  You can view all of the error  details - here's how: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1352948/how-to-get-all-errors-from-asp-net-mvc-modelstate

Comment: Do you have `@model EFGetStarted.AspNetCore.NewDb.Models.Blog` at the top?

Comment: @prospector Yes, I do have that on top and it does get recognized by intellisense as well.

Comment: @prospector I resolved the issue. Please see UPDATE 2 in my post.

Comment: Consider posting this is a self-answer so it plays nice with searches, etc.

Comment: @jdphenix Per your advice I just did it -explaining the details. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved the issue. There was a **mistake on my part**. I was using the datatype `int` in the property `public int Url { get; set; }` of the Blog class. Changed it to string. Then deleted the database in SQL Server and corresponding migration folder in the project. Re-ran the package manager commands `Add-Migration MyFirstMigration -context BloggingContext` and `Update-Database -context BloggingContext`. It's working now. Although the app was a copy/paste from this [Microsoft Tutorial](https://docs.efproject.net/en/latest/platforms/aspnetcore/new-db.html), later I tried to test creating a property through a short-cut key as [explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3871280/1232087) but forgot that the short-cut key creates the datatype as `int`. Thanks to all the readers who may have tried to help.