# Visual Studio propertie autocode

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I am using Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2015 and when I define a private variable and I use the tool "Quick actions and refactors..." (right clicking on the variable) I get the next auto-code:

```
private List<Test> tests;

public List<Test> Tests
{
    get
    {
       return tests;
    }

    set
    {
        tests = value;
    }
}
```

I do not like this long branches, I would prefer something like:

```
public List<Test> Tests
{
    get { return tests; }
    set { tests = value; }
}
```

There is a way of change this behavior?

EDIT:

What I am asking is not the same than the question linked (when marked as duplicated). I was wondering if once the variable is **already** created I can generate a propertie in the form I want, not to generate a new variable.

Comment: Create your own code snippet.

Answer (score 1):

Just write `propfull` and hit Tab twice. Look also this answer [Shortcut to create properties in Visual Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3871270/shortcut-to-create-properties-in-visual-studio)